# Will a "scheduled for maintenance" instance be drained gracefully before being stopped?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

Recently received the typical "scheduled for maintenance" notice on four instances, two of which are in ELBs:

[image]

Will the connections on these instances be drained gracefully if I just let AWS stop the instances or do I need to remove them manually, stop and start them and then re-add them?

Answer (score 0):

They will likely just shut down.  The `system-reboot` instances will come back up on their own.  The `instance-stop` instances will not, because their hardware is being retired due to degradation.  These could actually fail at any time, depending on the nature of the degradation... so fixing them sooner is better than later.

In both cases, removing the instances from the balancer, then stop/start, then adding the instances back to the balancer, is the cleanest solution and will clear these statuses because the instances will migrate to new hardware when you start them after a stop.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer, but that wasn't actually my question.  My question is, if I do nothing, will the instances be removed from the ELBs gracefully...IOW, will the ELB be allowed to finish in-flight requests before the instance is take down?

Comment: Sorry... the first sentence was intended to be the answer to your question.  It is unlikely to be graceful, because they will likely just shut down.  Also, two will recover, two won't